# How to truncate a comma-separated value string with remainder count

Tags: swift

I'm trying to achieve string truncate with "&  more..." when string is truncated. I have this in picture:

[image]

Exact code minus text, in image:

```swift
func formatString() -> String {
    let combinedLength = 30
    
    // This array will never be empty
    let strings = ["Update my profile", "Delete me", "Approve these letters"]

    // In most cases, during a loop (no order of strings)
    //let strings = ["Update", "Delete", "Another long word"]
  
    let rangeNum = strings.count > 1 ? 2 : 1
    
    let firstN = strings[0..<rangeNum]
    
    // A sum of first 2 or 1
    let actualLength = firstN.compactMap { $0.count }.reduce(0, +)

    switch actualLength {
    case let x where x <= combinedLength:
        // It's safe to display all
        return strings.map{String($0)}.joined(separator: ", ")
    default:
        
        if rangeNum == 2 {
            if actualLength <= combinedLength {
                return strings.first! + ", " + strings[1] + ", & \(strings.count - 2) more..."
            }
            
            return strings.first! + ", & \(strings.count - 1) more..."
        }
        
        // There has to be at least one item in the array.
        return strings.first!
    }
}
```

While [truncateMode](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/text/truncationmode(_:)) looks like a match, it's missing the `, & n more...` where `n` is the remainder.

My code may not be perfect but was wondering how to refactor. I feel there's a bug in there somewhere. I've not taken into consideration for larger screens: iPad where I would want to display more comma-separated values, I only look for the max 2 then display "& n more" depending on the size of the array.

Is there a hidden modifier for this? I'm using XCode 13.4.1, targeting both iPhone and iPad.

Edit:

The title is incorrect. I want to convert an array of strings into a comma-separated value string that's truncated using the function I have.

Comment: Assuming that your length might differ based on width of device, you can try getting the length of view i.e., your names container and start pushing each value in the container and removing it from the actual list until the ```container.length < values_inside``` and then count the remaining values in the actual list.

Comment: Hi thanks. Could do. I'll see what that looks like.

Comment: and 1 more thing since you are including ```& x more...``` in that same container you could do something like this: ```container  = extracted_names + "&" + count(remaining_list) + " more..."``` and then compare ```container.length < values_inside``` I'm not a swift dev but this is how the flow will go.